# How to make <select> of materialize-css work with reactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, materialize

I have added the following code for making a `<select>` field in component.

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

It needs `$('select').material_select();` to initialize the field.

when I added it like

```
componentDidMount(){
    $('select').material_select();
  }
```

It shows error like this `'$' is not defined  no-undef`

Help me solve it..

Comment: `$` stands for `jquery`. So I guess you need it in order to use this `select`.

Comment: It did solved the problem. I added `import $ from 'jquery';` and it worked.. Thank you...